# Date Validation according to different type

Tags: forms, rules

I met a problem when create a new content.

I created a content type, it has a field named Type, this field have two values.
When select "normal", another field Date will be hidden. When select "renewal", another field Date will display.

Now I want to compare start date and end date before save this content.
On one way, I used field validation, but it always give warning for both "normal" and "renewal".

On the other, I add new rules to compare the date, but it gives warning always after saved the content.

Anyone could help me to solve this problem? very appreciate for this.

Comment: Solved this question. use field validation php code.
if($this->value > $this->entity->{field_sry_end_date}['und'][0]['value'] && $this->entity->{field_sry_type}['und'][0]['value'] == 'renewal'){
$this->set_error();
}

Answer (score 0):

use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on both the date fields and then compare that value in the validate function of the form.

Comment: hi harshal,thank you for your answer.as i am very new in drupal,do you mean I need to write module by myself to solve this problem?could you explain more?Very appreciate for this.

Comment: yes u would need to write a module for it.